# redis slave: unable to connect to master: invalid argument

Tags: redis

On my slave redis server, after executing 'slaveof master_hostname 7804', it keeps logging the following messages:

```
Connecting to MASTER master_hostname:7804
Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
```

On the Linux server that hosts my slave redis server, I can connect to my master redis server without any problem:

```
$ redis-cli -h master_hostname -p 7804
```

The output of 'info' on master:

```
# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
```

The output of 'info' on slave:

```
# Replication
role:slave
master_host:master_hostname
master_port:7804
master_link_status:down
master_last_io_seconds_ago:-1
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:1
master_link_down_since_seconds:1428997735
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
```

Both redis servers are 3.0.0.  If I use the IP of the master redis server instead of its hostname, I meet the same problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I am having the exactly same issue here. I'm using Redis 3.0.0 in both machines (master and slave).

I've tried `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1`, but still not working.

In my case, I'm using CentOS 6.6.

EDIT:
I've found the solution! In **slave** config, if you have configured `bind 127.0.0.1`, then you need to change to `bind 192.168.1.54` (where 192.168.1.54 is the **slave IP**). Remember that master is in the same network 192.168.1.*.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Edward, I've related that I was having the same issue, but I wrote a hint for him (using sysctl). Then I've made a comment to my answer with the solution for his question.

Comment: I see that now. Please [edit] your comment into the answer so it is very clear that this post answers the question! (We try to keep Answer Posts to only actual answers) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with Redis 3 in MASTER-SLAVE setup.

I changed `bind 127.0.0.1 10.234.1.10` to `bind 10.234.1.10 127.0.0.1` and it works!

So, it looks, that "127.0.0.1" cannot be first in the list.

Comment: Worked for me too, Do you have any idea why it works?

Comment: Asked on their mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/KrGjvnIauAI  the answer is it uses the first IP to announce itself